# Animation of two plots

Tags: graphics, functions, animation

I have some problems with animation of two functions. I want to add another function to this code:

```
Animate[
 Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[x], Sin[x]}}], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

This function should depend on `x` too. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Animate[Graphics[{Red, 
   Line[{{{0, 0}, {Cos[x], Sin[x]}}, {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Cos[x], 
       Sin[x]}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}, {{0, 0}, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}}]}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Line can take multiple points to render independently. You could also create a line-strip without specifying the points in a separate list. 
I suggest your read trhough the documentation of [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html).

[image]